# Android - Googel Play Console Error "VALIDATE_APP_MESSAGE_NO_AUTOMOTIVE_SCREENSHOTS"

Tags: android, google-play-console

As soon as I want to update an App-Bundel in the Google Play Console, I get this message and it doesn't go any further.

**Unknown validation VALIDATE_APP_MESSAGE_NO_AUTOMOTIVE_SCREENSHOTS**

It is not clear to me what I should change in the app so that I can do this release.

Comment: does this app related to automotive or related things ?

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue. Did you find any solutions ?

Comment: @MonsterBrain Yes, it has something to do with automotive.

Comment: @Pierre How long have you had the problem, you know what you change?

Comment: In that case, did you missed uploading automotive based screenshot to the google play console?